# AS3 Getting MacAdress unique ID

Tags: actionscript-3

Why when I get MacAdress there is different Values when NetworkAdapter is Enabled and Disabled...? Please help, i need to take unique ID..

```
var networkInterface : Object =  NetworkInfo.networkInfo.findInterfaces();
var networkInfo  : Object = networkInterface[0];
var strNet : String = networkInfo.hardwareAddress.toString();
trace(strNet);
```

Comment: If you only need a Unique Identifier, use [UIDUtil](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/UIDUtil.html). You may need to find the source code for the class (it is not reliant on any of the Flex framework, I believe), but it works brilliantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe flash get mac address of default network interface from the OS. When you turn off one interface, OS get another as default. As mentioned by Apocalyptic0n3, using UID is a better way. And you can save UID in Flash Shared Object for next running...